# How to resize an html5 image for mobile

Tags: html, wordpress, mobile

I apologize in advance for not figuring out how to format this correctly

I converted a flash swf that contained buttons and very simple action script to an html5 file. I uploaded the .html and put it onto my wordpress website using an iframe code I found online:

```
    <div id="iframewrap"><iframe id="iframeid" name="iframeName" src="test.html" 
height="578" width="110%" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 
scrolling="yes"></iframe></div>

<style type="text/css"><!--#iframewrap { width: 110%; padding: 0px;
top:-25px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;} #iframeid { width:110%;
height:578px; margin:10px 10px 10px 10px; overflow:hidden;} #iframeid
{ -ms-zoom: 0.9; -moz-transform: scale(0.9); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(0.9); -o-transform-origin: 0 0; -webkit-transform:
scale(0.9); -webkit-    transform-origin: 0 0;
} --><style>--></style>
```

It looks fine on the website but is way too big for the mobile version. If I adjust any of the scales (changing .9 to .25) it affects the original site as well. Is there a way I can leave the original site at .9 and have a mobile device change it to .25?

Comment: There's still no good solution for responsive iframes. I'm curious, since what you're looking for per your title is a "response image", why you're using an iframe instead of a simple `img` tag?

Comment: I converted an swf to an html5 file and couldn't get the img tags to work with it. The iframe ended up working, so I just have to get it to scale.

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi Is there a way I can use img tags that will load this html5 image? I converted the swf with google swiffy.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If it's a video, you should use a HTML5 support video format, and if it's an image, why not use a common format like jpg, png or gif?

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi It is neither a video nor an image, it contains buttons and action script. It appears to be an image of several artists in black and white and when you hover over each artist, the image turns color on and when you click you go their that artist's page. I am working in wordpress which can be very limiting at times and flash to html5 was my work-around, besides for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [media query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries) is what you are looking for:

```
@media screen and ( max-width : 500px ) {
  #iframeid {
    -ms-zoom: 0.25;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
    -o-transform: scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.25);  
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it makes the iframe not load at all on a mobile device and still loads fine on a computer.